# How to modify a recursion to a loop version in this case?

Tags: data-structures, compiler-construction, recursion, binary-tree, tail-recursion

I want to modify the c++ code below, to use loop instead of recursion. 
I know of 2 ways to modify it:

1. Learn from the code and make a loop algorithm. In this case I think the meaning of code is to printB (except leaf) and printA (expect root) by level order. For a binary (search) tree, how can I traverse it from leaf to root in a loop (without a pointer to parent)?
2. Use a stack to imitate the process on the stack. In the case, I can't make it, can you help me and say some useful thinking?

   ```
   void func(const Node& node) {

       if (ShouldReturn(node)) {
           return;
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < node.children_size(); ++i) {
           const Node& child_node = node.child(i);
           func(child_node);
           PrintA();
       }

       PrintB();
   }
   ```

Comment: what does this function "ShouldReturn(node)" do . Please elaborate a bit more about problem statement . What do you want to achieve in program .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C++

For the stack part, lets say, the code does the following.

1. If Node was leaf, nothing.
2. Else do the same for each child,then printA after each.
3. then printB.

So what if I adjusted the code alittle. The adjustments only to fit for iterative way.

```
void func(const Node& node) {
    if(ShouldReturn(node)) return;
    PrintB();
    for(int i = 0; i < node.children_size(); ++i) {
        printA();
        const Node& child_node = node.child(i);
        func(child_node, false);
    }
}
// This way should make it print As & Bs in reverse direction.
// Lets re-adjust the code even further.

void func(const Node& node, bool firstCall = true) {
    if(!firstCall) printA; //Placed that here, as printA is always called if a new Node is called, but not for the root Node, that's why I added the firstCall.
    if(ShouldReturn(node)) return;
    PrintB();
    for(int i = 0; i < node.children_size(); ++i) {
        const Node& child_node = node.child(i);
        func(child_node, false);
    }
}
```

That should reverse the order of printing A & B, I hope I'm not wrong :D
So, now I want to have 2 vectors.

```
// Lets define an enum
typedef enum{fprintA, fprintB} printType;

void func(const Node& node){
     vector<printType> stackOfPrints;
     vector<Node*> stackOfNodes; stackOfNodes.push_back(node);
     bool first = true; //As we don't need to printA before the root.
     while ((int)stackOfNodes.size() > 0){
         const Node& fNode = stackOfNodes.back();
         stackOfNodes.pop_back();
         if (!first) stackOfPrints.push_back(fprintA); // If not root printA.
         first = false;
         if(ShouldReturn(fNode)) continue;
         stackOfPrints.push_back(fprintB);
         // here pushing the Nodes in a reverse order so that to be processed in the stack in the correct order.
         for(int i = (int)fNode.children_size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
               stackOfNodes.push_back(fNode.child(i));
         }
     }

     // Printing the stackOfPrints in reverse order (remember we changed the code, to initially print As & Bs in reverse direction) 
     // this way, it will make the function print them in the correct required order
     while((int)stackOfPrints.size() > 0){
         switch(stackOfPrints.back()){
            case fprintA: printA(); break;
            case fprintB: printB(); break;
            default: break;
         };
         stackOfPrints.pop_back();
     }
}
```

Let's hope I write the code correctly. :) I hope it helps.

Comment: Your method is to transfer rec to tail rec, then loop~ thanks~ I have another thinking: as the case 1(-3)-2-4, func1(1)=f1{ f2{ f4{ blabla }//f4A4 }//f2A2 f3{ blabla }//f3A3 }//f1, then define "{fk" : push and  "}fk":if(ShouldReturn(node)) return;BK; => pop(); => Ak. Now if you have a loop version of DFS, it easily works!